# How to replicate bootstrap button style

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to replicate the bootstrap button style without having to import the bootstrap CDN into my project. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: You can copy only the relevant CSS from the source code. Just download it and pull out what you need.

Comment: it's scss, just copying the source code is difficult

Comment: You can download the rendered CSS https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css or if you download the zip, it's in \dist\css\

Comment: @Dog You can convert your scss code to css, there is an tool called SassMeister, you may want to try that out https://www.sassmeister.com/

Comment: if you don't have the defined mixins you can't compile them through that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Open this page - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/ and check/uncheck what you want

In your case you need to check

Common CSS - Buttons

Components - Buttons groups

Your custom version of Bootstrap is now ready to be compiled. Just click the button below to finish the process.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Download the package here: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/

Then open it and go into the SCSS directory. Look for _buttons.scss.

Open it, copy the styles, paste them into your CSS. You may have to hard code any SASS vars they use.

Comment: Not everyone uses SASS.

Comment: just copying that file isn't going to work because the SASS mixins aren't included

Comment: ---> "You may have to hard code any SASS vars they use."